# How can I retrieve the complete "Documents and Data" from iCloud to my Mac?

Tags: data-synchronization, books

Is there a way to get to complete "Document and Data" to the Mac?
[image]
P.S.: All datas where uploaded via my ipad, most of it is in IBooks, a lot of Pdfs and ebooks (not from the store). The thing is
1) My ~/Library/Mobile Documents is nearly empty
2) My Ibook-app on the Mac is completely empty.

Answer (score 1):

The folder's already on your Mac. Your data is accessible in **~/Library/Mobile Documents**.